# datetimeoffset vs datetime2 for UTC on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, utc, datetimeoffset

Are there any benefits to storing a UTC timestamp in a datetimeoffset field vs datetime2? It seems they're essentially the same.

```
+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| datetimeoffset                     | datetime2                   |
|------------------------------------+-----------------------------|
| 2021-02-12 16:48:11.0677934 +00:00 | 2021-02-12 16:48:11.0677934 |
+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: A `datetime2` of the same precision will be smaller in storage terms. If you aren't planning to ever store anything other than UTC, then use `datetime2`.

Comment: Datetime offset will allow comparison between different offsets of the same time. e.g. `CAST('2021-02-12 15:48:11.0677934 -01:00' AS datetimeoffset) = CAST('2021-02-12 16:48:11.0677934 +00:00' AS datetimeoffset)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `datetimeoffset` data type will allow comparison between different offsets of the same time. e.g.:

```
SELECT 'equal'
WHERE
    CAST('2021-02-12T15:48:11.0677934-01:00' AS datetimeoffset) = CAST('2021-02-12T16:48:11.0677934+00:00' AS datetimeoffset).
```

If you are storing only UTC values (where the offset is always zero), you can save storage space with [`datetime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) requires 10 bytes of storage whereas `datetime2` needs 8 bytes for precision 5 or greater, 7 bytes for precision 3-4, and 6 bytes for precision 2 or less.